# C# Convert a long string in format "Table.Col [,Table.Col]" to Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a string which contains list of `Tablename.Colname` separated by comma. Example:

```
"SoMast.SoNo,ItemMast.ItemNo,ItemDetail.ItemId"
```

I would like to convert this string to a `Dictionary<string,string>` object where first string is table name and second is column name - with as few lines as possible.

Edit: Thanks for quick responses. Once problem that I didn't mention until I ran into it is, if the above string contains a duplicate table name - such as `"Somast.SoNo,Somast.Custno"`, dictionary will fail. **Is there an alternate soln?**

Comment: How about you show us your effort first?

Comment: I've first used string.Split(',') to convert it to a list. From there I loop and extract second part using Split('.'), and Add the parts to a Dictionary object. The code is so simplistic I figured its not worthwhile to post it. Thx though.

Comment: @ConnieFernandez It is always a good idea to post your code, no matter how trivial it is, simply to convince people that you do *not* want them to do your work for you.

Comment: In response to your edit. How do you want it to work? Perhaps a ILookup would fit your needs better?

Comment: I will try to learn and use ILookup (I hadn't heard of if until now).

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
str.Split(',').Select(s => s.Split('.')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

To handle duplicates as you describe in your edit you might want to use a `Lookup` instead of a dictionary. Change the code to use `.ToLookup` instead. `Lookup` is similar to dictionaries but holds a collection of values for a particular key.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var dict = list.Split(',').Select (split => split.Split('.')).ToDictionary (item => item[0], item => item[1]);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb549277.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Split the individual strings

```
text.Split(',').ToDictionary(x=> x.Split('.').First(), x=> x.Split('.').Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work i think.

```cs
var splitted = yourString.Split(',');
var resultDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(var entry in splittet){
    var splittedEntry = entry.Split('.');
    resultDict.Add(splittedEntry[0], splittedEntry[1]);
}
```